# Getting error when calling Powershell script Get-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRules?

Tags: powershell, azure-cli, powershell-ise

I am calling the following script

```
az login -u <USERNAME> -p <PWD> 
az account set --subscription Sub2
$sourceResourceGroup='Source-Networking'
$sourceSqlServerName='SourceSQLServer'
$sourceFirewallRules = Get-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName 
  $sourceResourceGroup -ServerName $sourceSqlServerName
```

The resourcegroup, 'Source-Networking' resides in subscription Sub2, but i get the error Resource Group 'Source-Networking' could not be found.
I am using Windows Powershell ISE as administrator to run the command.
It seems to work if i use the online Azure Cloud Shell on the Microsoft site where it says "try it".

What can be wrong in the ISE PowerShell window ?

Comment: Ensure that <USERNAME> and <PWD> used in the script have atleast read permissions on the RG. Also make sure the RG name is correct (including casing).

Comment: I have checked all that and it is fine. I was wondering if i need to escape the '- ' in the resource group name as it may be causing an issue in powershelll ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above shared script looks like you are trying to run the script with a combination of both AzureCLI & AzureRM modules wherein those scripts will fails in the ISE PowerShell window.

- You can refer the below script if you want to get the Sql server firewall rule using AzureCLI

```html
az login 
az account set --subscription '<<subscriptionId>>'
GroupName='resource-group-name'
ServerName='sql-server-name'
az sql server firewall-rule show --name firewall --resource-group $GroupName --server $ServerName
```

- You can refer the below script if you want to get the Sql server
  firewall rule using ISE  PowerShell & AzureRM module

```html
Connect-AzureRmAccount
Set-AzureRmContext -Subscription '<<subscriptionId>>'
$groupname = 'resource-group-name'
$serverName = 'sql-server-name'
$firewallrule = Get-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName $group -ServerName $servername
```